# PHP SMTP Mail alternatives to make it look prettier

Tags: php, email, html-email

I currently am using:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

To send emails to my members. The content of the email is been stored within the $body variable which makes it really difficult for template usage and basic attractiveness of the email.

My question is, is there an alternative or a method to implement a template into these sort of emails instead of the bog standard logo and text which looks horrendous!

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of sending the mail has nothing to do with its appearance. You can take any template engine you like and put it's output into $body. You should, however, embed it in a multipart message that contains a text/plain and a text/html part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com).  They have a free plan for 200 emails a day and a simple REST API to send emails.  You'll be able to make good looking templates and avoid the pain of [sending email](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html).